# How can I make a django query-set that uses two classes?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How can I link two classes in a django query set. For example I have a class Person and a class Department. A person has an attribute salary and a Department has the attribute leader. How can I do a query that gives me the salary of the leader of a department.

I am happy for any help :)

Comment: What kind of query you want ? Because queryset consists of objects, what you want is something different. Give more specific example

Comment: I am looking for something like: a = Person.objects.filter(salary = 100)

Comment: Answer is already below. But next time please be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a special query, the `leader` attribute on the `Department` object gives you access to a full `Person` object, with all its properties:

```
department = Department.objects.get(pk=1)
print(department.leader.salary)
```

Behind the scenes the code above will generate two SQL queriers. To make sure only one query is issued you can optionally use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
department = Department.objects.select_related('leader').get(pk=1)
print(department.leader.salary)
```

This way Django will fetch information about the leader's `Person` object during the original query (instead of the usual "lazy" approach of waiting until it is actually needed). This however is only an optimization and often times isn't really needed.

---

In case you want to filter a queryset using a field from an object across a relationship, you can use [the `__` notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), which represents the relationship between two models:

```
departments = Department.objects.filter(leader__salary=100)
```